# Android OpenCV error when converting Mat to Android bitmap

Tags: opencv, java-native-interface, android

I'm writing an application that streams video from a webcam to an android device. The streaming client is written in C++ and uses imencode to compress images so they can be sent over UDP. I have a mock "receiver", also in C++, that can receive the images and display them. I'm porting the receiver to Android, and using only the opencv java sdk (I am not writing my own JNI stuff). The code that converts the received byte array into a Mat and then a bitmap is as follows -

```
Mat frame = Highgui.imdecode(new MatOfByte(packet.getData()), 0);
bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame.cols(), frame.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(frame, bm);
im.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        im.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
});
```

The call to `Util.matToBitmap` gives the following error -

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) >= 0) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean), file /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp, line 99 03-04 19:04:46.337  15034-15148/ E/org.opencv.android.Utils﹕ nMatToBitmap catched cv::Exception: /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:99: error: (-215) AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) >= 0 in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean) 03-04 19:04:46.452  15034-15148/E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-924
```

This is only a slight modification of previously working code that used TCP, and I can not find what this error actually means. Anyone know what's going on? Or any suggestions on how to debug JNI code that I didn't write?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure, I cannot test that now, but I suppose your Matrix and Bitmap needs to have the same dimensions. You probably need to create an empty Matrix with Bitmap's dimensions first and then Fill it up with the Data you receive.

Or at least debug the app to check if they have the same dimensions.

**EDIT :** So, I've checked out one of my previous projects and here how I was creating the Bitmap, check the code below. The difference is in the methods of the Mat Object. I was using `mat.getWidth()` instead of `mat.cols()` This might be the reason of that exception. Give it a try.

```
Bitmap frame = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.width(), mat.height(), Config.ARGB_8888);
```